# Different Behaviour of cindent Between vim 7.0 and vim 7.2

Tags: linux, vim, parentheses, auto-indent

I am using a .vimrc file on one machine that indents my parentheses exactly how I like them using the following lines:

```
set tabstop=3
set shiftwidth=3   
set ai
set cindent
set cino=(s,U1,)0,m1
```

The machine this works on is running RHEL5 with vim 7.0. However, on my newer machine running RHEL6 with vim 7.2 this doesn't work anymore. In fact, it seems that no matter how I modify cino nothing seems to change. What am I missing? Has syntax changed between the versions?

Comment: what is the output of `:echo has('cindent')`? `1`?

Comment: do you run your vim in `compatible` mode?

Comment: After running `:set compatible` and `:set nocompatible` I get the same results. EDIT: Actually I do get different results, but they are still not the correct ones.

Comment: Did you compare the documentation between the 2 versions? Some values of `'cinoptions'` may have different meanings…

Comment: Do you have the filetype plugin indent on?

Comment: The documentation in `:help cinoptions-values` reveals the same page it seems.

Comment: Could the .vim files for indentation and highlighting cause issues like this?

Comment: @doliver, I tried turning it on and off and still had the same results. I even tried copying over the scheme.vim files over from my old machine to the new one with no success.

Comment: What do you get from ':verbose set cino?'

Comment: @doliver , after running `:verbose set cino` I get: `cinoptions=(s,U1,)0,m1`. I get the same ouput on both my RHEL 6 and RHEL 5 machines.

Comment: Does your RHEL6/vim 7.2 machine have a default .vimrc that is getting called before your personal one? I've had that burn me before.

Comment: @patrickvacek I would have thought that, but when I manually type `set cino=(s,U1,)0,m1` in vim, I don't get the results I am looking for unfortunately.

Comment: So I found that if I change my file extension from .scm to .cpp (or c for that matter) I get the tabbing I want. I don't get the highlighting that I want. So until I can figure out how to use the highlight for scheme files and tabbing for c, I just edit file like normal with the .scm extension, then when I am ready to tab, I just change it to .cpp to get the tabbing. Anyone know of a better way to do this?